# Delegate is nil in Alamofire response callback

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I want to use my custom delegate methods in Alamofire's response callback, like below:

```
func startDownloadSegment() {
  let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
    let filePath = self.generateFilePath()

    return (filePath, [.createIntermediateDirectories])
  }

  // 1
  print(self.delegate)

  Alamofire.download(downloadURL, to: destination).response { response in
    // 2
    print(self.delegate)

    if response.error == nil {
      self.delegate?.segmentDownloadSucceeded(with: self)
    } else {
      self.delegate?.segmentDownloadFailed(with: self)
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, No.1 print(self.delegate) returns the delegator I set. But No.2 always returns nil so delegate method like downloadSucceeded(with:) cannot be called.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you set the delegate?

Comment: Showing more code , delegate implementation part too might help

Comment: @NSNoob Yes, delegate is set. I updated my question.

Comment: If delegate is `nil` it's **not** set.

Comment: I can't see any useful update here (Any update at all really).  If you had set the delegate, it wouldn't be null. Add the part where you set the delegate

Comment: @NSNoob now it's updated :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the problem. The problem is I set the delegate as

> weak var delegate

But as in Alamofire response callback, I should omit 'weak' keyword to get it done.